# Reference for spectral theorem for normal operators.

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

Does anyone know of a good reference for the spectral theorem (projection valued measure version) for possibly unbounded normal operators? I would also be interested in examples where this sort of theorem still holds for non-normal operators. Thanks!

Comment: For spectral theorems for unbounded normal operators you can use Rudin's FA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of detail in Section 5.6 of Kadison-Ringrose (Fundamentals of the Theory of Operator Algebras).

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect!