# Proof of multiplication operator form of spectral theorem for unbounded normal operators

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, operator-theory, spectral-theory, unbounded-operators

I'm looking for a proof that

> Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space and $N$ an unbounded normal operator on $H$. Then there is a finite measure space $(X,\scr{M},\mu)$, a unitary operator $U:H\to L^2(\mu)$, and a complex measurable function $f$ such that: (i) for $x\in H$, $x\in D(N)$ iff $f\,Ux\in L^2(\mu)$; (ii) for $\phi\in U(D(A))$, $UNU^{-1}\phi=f\phi$. In other words, $N$ becomes multiplication by $f$.

If $N$ is bounded, this can be found in *A Course in Functional Analysis* by G. B. Folland; however this book does not address unbounded operators. If $N$ is unbounded but self-adjoint, this can be found in *Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I: Functional Analysis* by M. Reed & B. Simon; however this book does not seem to care about unbounded normal operators.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3064754/reference-for-spectral-theorem-for-normal-operators

Comment: @KeithMcClary That question is about the projection valued measure form of the spectral theorem, and I already know its proof (from Rudin's book). But how can we deduce the multiplication operator form from that form?

Comment: [Relevant?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/310874/unbounded-version-of-continuous-functional-calculus)